# Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2015 playback is too fast, renders are regular speed though

Tags: premiere, playback

Trying to figure out why my playback on the timeline (no matter the sequence settings) is slightly faster. Any possible fixes, or ways to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that there isn't a misconfig of framerate between **original media**, **sequence** and **export**.

*Eg:* Original 25fps, Sequence at 30fps and exported at 25fps.

In this case the playback would appear faster in premiere, but ok in the exported media.